# How to get depth data using python api

Tags: python, depth-of-field

I know how to do this manually but I want to know how to do this with a python script. I was trying to use nodes to connect the z buffer to the output.
However, when I save this, the outputs are all 0s and 1s.

```
#switch on nodes
scene.use_nodes = True
tree = scene.node_tree
links = tree.links

# clear default nodes
for n in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(n)

# create input render layer node
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')    

# create defocus layer
d = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeDefocus')
d.use_zbuffer = True

# create output node
v = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')   
v.use_alpha = False

# Links
links.new(rl.outputs[0], d.inputs[0])  # link Image output to defocus Image
links.new(rl.outputs[2], d.inputs[1]) # link Z-Buffer output to defocus Z
links.new(d.outputs[0], v.inputs[0])

# render
bpy.ops.render.render()

# get viewer pixels
pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
print(len(pixels)) # size is always width * height * 4 (rgba)

# copy buffer to numpy array for faster manipulation
arr = np.array(pixels[:])
fname = "depth.npz"
with open(fname, "wb") as f:
    np.savez(f, arr)
```

Comment: Well, when I try your code and load the resulting file I see a lot of values, many of which are neither zero nor 1.  Maybe you're looking at the alpha channel of the RGBA which is mostly going to be zero (transparent) or 1 (opaque).  I do not see any place where you tried to save the Z buffer.  You didn't even link the Z output to the viewer's Z input.  Maybe you want to render the image to an EXR (instead of PNG) including Z Buffer checkbox.  Please clarify your question to address some of this confusion.

Comment: I thought the line:
`links.new(rl.outputs[2], d.inputs[1]) # link Z-Buffer output to defocus Z`
connects the z output to the defocus z. which is then combined to the output image which is connected to the viewer in:
`links.new(rl.outputs[2], d.inputs[1]) # link Z-Buffer output to defocus Z`

Am I not correctly linking the z output to the z input?

Comment: That links it to the defocus node, but it does not link the Z to the Z input on the viewer, and there seems to be no Composite node (which is the "true" output of the compositor for a regular file output).

Answer (score 5):

Ok. I finally got the depth data by directly connecting the z data to the viewer node:

```
# create input render layer node
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')    

# create output node
v = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')   
v.use_alpha = False

# Links
links.new(rl.outputs['Z'], v.inputs[0]) # link Z to output

# render
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

And then I output the information into an npz file to be used within python

```
# get viewer pixels
pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels
print(len(pixels)) # size is always width * height * 4 (rgba)

# copy buffer to numpy array for faster manipulation
arr = np.array(pixels[:])
fname2 = "depth.npz" 
with open(fname2, "wb") as f:
    np.savez(f, arr)
```